# Sudoku Solver: How do you remove a possibility from a row/column?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

Here is a newbie question: I am implementing a 9X9 sudoku using numpy array. Every cell has 9 possibilities [1-9], I have filled every cell to '123456789' string to represent all possibilities. I have further flattened this to get a [81X1] array
Sudoku starts with some given numbers. I can read them from a csv thus getting the index and value. Next step is to use the index to identify row & column and then delete the value (string equivalent) from all cells in the same row/column/block. rem_1() below is trivial.

How do I "apply" rem_1 only on cells in the same row/col without doing loops? I will deal with the blocks later :)

```
def rem_1(poss, num):
    return poss.replace(str(num), '')
sud = np.full((9,9), '123456789')
sud_flat= sud.reshape(81,1)
csv = np.genfromtxt ('SudokuEx1.csv', delimiter=",", skip_header=1, dtype=int)
ID = csv[:,0] # this will be used to identify row/col
Val = csv[:,3] #this is the value I need to remove from all row/col cells except the ID'ed cell
```

Comment: I have also made a sudoku solver, and my method (which sounds easier) was to have a 9X9 of lists where each list starts with `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` unless it is a given value. Then you just `del item` from the list. When there is one item left in the list you have solved that square! I prefer this method because converting to/from integers and strings along with reshaping arrays sounds tedious. Good luck!

Comment: It sounds like you want to know how to get all of the indexes for a single row or a single columyon in a 9x9 matrix that has been flattened to 1x81 array.  Is that right?  To do 1 row, you'd just start at the first cell in the row.  That would have index **9 * <row>**.  And then you'd add 1 each time to get next index... **9 * <row> + 1, 9 * <row> + 2...**.  To do a column, you would start with first cell in column, which would be the column number (**<col>**) and then you'd add 9 each time to get next index in column... **<col>  + 1 * 9, <col> + 2 * 9...**.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Why would you make it an 81x1 array? Conceptually that's much harder to work with than 9x9. You can easily make one function that checks the 9 rows in your `sud` array, then use the same function on `sud.transpose()` on the 9 columns. To check the 3x3 sub-arrays, you can just slice them and then use `flatten()` to make it 1d. 2) I second @Reedinationer's idea of preferring a list to a string. In the solver I have written, I used an `int` to store the actual answer value so I could then identify answers by type rather than len.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I figured all cells in an numpy array have to have the same dtype. There is another which explains how complicated it is to create a 2-D array of lists. My solution was to have a string "123456789", instead of a list of integers, from which you can always drop letters as you solve another cell in the same row or column. I agree that flattening into 81X1 is not a great idea. David's idea of using dtype to different possibilities Vs confirmed number is also excellent.